# Partial derivatives defined everywhere yet $f$ is not differentiable everywhere in $\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider $f(x,y)$ defined as $\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq0$ and defined to be $0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Now the question asks to show that all partial derivatives exist, yet the function is not differentiable at the point $(0,0)$

My current thinking is, that since
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$$ and the function is clearly differentiable/continuous at every other point, then we can conclude that the partial derivatives exist at any point?

But I can't see why this function wouldn't be differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: Did you check the partial derivatives exist **at** $\;(0,0)\;$ ? This is a *necessary* condition...

Comment: Just manually taking the partial derivative seems to indicate that it's not the case -- so does this mean I have to take the limit definition of the partial? 

What about the differentiability at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Just because the partial derivatives exist does not necessarily mean that you have differentiability. Differentiability of a scalar function $f$ of a vector variable $x$ at a point $x_0$ means that there is a vector $v$ such that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-v \cdot h}{\| h \|} = 0$, where $h$ here is a vector variable going to the zero vector and $\| h \|$ denotes the length of $h$.

Comment: This vector, when it exists, is the gradient, i.e. the vector of partial derivatives. But the partial derivatives can sometimes exist even when the function is not differentiable. The "standard" result that ensures this doesn't happen requires that the partial derivatives be *continuous* at the point of interest. So to get your result you must first invalidate the hypotheses of this one, by showing that the partial derivatives of your function, although they exist at $(0,0)$, are not continuous there.

Comment: You say "My current thinking is, that since 
$lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)} f(x,y)=0$ and the function is clearly differentiable/continuous at every other point, then we can conclude that the partial derivatives exist at any point?"  No, that doesn't follow.  The function g(x)= |x| is "clearly differentiable/continuous at every other point" (and continuous at x= 0) but not differentiable at x= 0.  And functions of more than one variable, since there are many more ways by which to "approach" a point, tend to be much more complicated.

Comment: @HughEntwistle You lost me: if one of $\;f_x(0,0)\;$ or $\;f_y(0,0)\;$ doesn't exist, then the function cannot be differentiable at the origin. Now, if the partial derivatives at that point  do exist, then **it can be the function is differentiable** at that point... yet we still have to check.

Comment: @DonAntonio using the limit definition for partial derivatives, I was able to find that partials with respect to $x$ and $y$ are $1$ and $-1$ respectively. 

But that does not let us conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ since the partial derivatives exist, we still have to check other things?

Comment: @Ian how would I show they are not continuous? By taking the limit of my expressions for the partials?

Comment: UPDATE (Possible Solution) 

So I thought to take the directional derivative of $f$ (since i know the gradient) 

So $df = (1,-1)\cdot(a,b) : ||(a,b)||=1$ 

Let $(a,b) = ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(a,b)=(1,0)$. 

So we see that two different directions yield a different derivative. Hence the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: That is another way to do it (working pretty much directly from the definition).

Comment: So it is a valid argument @ian ?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid approach.

Comment: @HughEntwistle You lost me: you're taking the directional derivative *at what point* and in what direction? Why do you think that getting different dir. derivatives *towards different* directions would yield a contradiction, again?

Comment: @DonAntonio We can argue that the derivative of the point (0,0) of f only exists if it is defined in all directions. 

Now I found the gradient and then introduced an arbitrary unit vector. But it can be seen that the derivatives are not equal in two different directions, so we conclude that the derivative at (0,0) does not exist. Hence f is not differentiable at (0,0). -- Am I making sense?

Comment: @HughEntwistle Either you're confusing things big time here...or else I am: do you think that if your function is **differentiable** at the origin, then the directional derivatives **in all the directions** are equal?

Comment: Yes thats what I thought was the case.

Comment: @HughEntwistle I don't think that is true. What is true, if I'm not pretty mistaken, is that if a function is differentiable at some point $\;P\;$, then the directional derivative at that point **in all directions** exists, but this doesn't mean they all are equal!  We have that in the direction $\;u\;$ the dir. derivative is given by the very nice and simple formula$$f_u(P)=\nabla f(P)\cdot u$$ but, of course, the above number depends on *each* $\;u\;$ ! I just read your interchange with Ian and I think he also got confused at this...or, as many other times, I did.

Comment: Yes this makes sense -- I too was getting confused. So how can we show that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @HughEntwistle Read my answer. Hopefully you'll find it clear. Any doubt write back in the comments under it.

Comment: Er, yes, I'm sorry, the directional derivative will depend on the direction. But it could depend on the direction in "the wrong way": for example, if the $x$ partial is $1$ and the $y$ partial is $-1$ then the directional derivative in the direction of $(1,1)$ had better be $0$ for us to have differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check:

$$f_x(0,0):=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{x^3}{x^2}}x=1$$

$$f_y(0,0):=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}y=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-\frac{x^y}{y^2}}y=-1$$

Thus, **if** $\;f\;$ **is differentiable at the origin**, then the directional derivative at $\;(0,0)\;$ in *any* direction $\;(a,b)\;$ is given by $\;\nabla f(0,0)\cdot(a,b)=(1,-1)(a,b)=a-b\;$

Thus, for example in the direction $\;u:=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\,-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\;$ we'd get that $\;f_u(0,0)=\sqrt2\;$ , yet **by definition**:

$$f_u(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\overbrace{f\left(h\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right)-f(0)}^{f\left(\frac h{\sqrt2},-\frac h{\sqrt2}\right)-0}}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{\frac{h^3}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{h^3}{2\sqrt2}}{\frac{h^2}2+\frac{h^2}2}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{h^3}{\sqrt2}}{h^3}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\neq\sqrt2$$

and thus $\;f\;$ cannot be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: This makes sense but I am also curious as to why this is the case! 

Consider $\frac{ \partial f }{\partial x} = \frac{ x^4 + 3x^2y^2+2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq0$ and is $1$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ 

But the partial derivative needs to be continuous about $(0,0)$ in order for $f$ to be differentiable.  Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{ \partial f }{\partial x}(x,x)\neq lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{ \partial f }{\partial x}(x,0)$ we conclude that the partial is not continuous and hence $f$ is not differentiable?

Comment: @HughEntwistle Nop. A function can be differentiable at a point and its partial derivatives can be non-continuous there! The condition is sufficient, not necessary.

Comment: Hmm.. So what's going on here? Is there a way to explain why we reached the contradiction outlined in your answer?

Comment: @HughEntwistle (1) If the function is diff. at zero, then the directional der. at the origin in any direction is given by the formula with the nabla as shown in the answer, and the dir. der. exists **in any direction** (these are standard theorems). (2) There's a direction where the definition of direc. deriv. and the above mentioned formula give different results. Contradiction.

Comment: Hmm I meant more along the lines of WHY there was a contradiction -- (I completely understand your working, thank you so much for bearing it out with me :) ) 

I need to sit down for a couple of hours with a big old Calculus book! I feel my lecturer skips over a lot of these more important definitions

Comment: There are several hundreds, if not thousands, of calculus books to consult and even to download in the web, and several tens of thousands sites more where you can check this.